# Shortening RegEx for Perl

Tags: regex, perl, language-agnostic

I have created a regexp in Perl that is about 95 characters in length, I wish to shorten it to 78 characters but can't find a suitable method. Any advice welcome, the regexp is similar to the code below, ideally there is something similar to \ in C.

```
my ($foo, $bar, $etc) = $input_line =~ 
/^\d+: ....  (\X+)\(\X(\d+.\d+|\d+)\/\X(\d+.\d+|\d+) (\X+)\)$/
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to shorten the expression to *78* characters? why not 79 or 77 ?

Comment: Oh, and we might be able to help you more if we knew what the expression (which, by the way, you did *not* post) is supposed to do.

Comment: @thkala - maybe because of some coding style asking the lines to contain not more than 79 characters (preferrably 78)?

Comment: I make all my terminals/code default 78 chars wide, just a preference. Also I'm not really looking to change the Regexp if possible - just wrap it over two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl interpolates regex, so you could do something like this

```
my $input_line = '123: ....  X(X1.1/X5 XXX)';

 my $dOrI = '(\d+.\d+|\d+)';
 my ($foo, $bar, $etc) = $input_line =~ 
 /^\d+: ....  (\X+)\(\X$dOrI\/\X$dOrI (\X+)\)$/;

print "$foo, $bar, $etc";
```

---

Output -

```
X, 1.1, 5
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to tell regex to skip embedded whitespace and comments, so not only you can split it up into multiple lines, but also comment it, format it to sections etc. I think it's 'x', but I don't have documentation handy right now, so look it up in the man page.

So you'd change it to something like:

```
my ($foo, $bar, $etc) = $input_line =~ /
        ^\d+: ....
        (\X+)\(
            \X(\d+.\d+|\d+) # numerator
            \/\X(\d+.\d+|\d+) # denominator
            \ (\X+)\)$/x # mind the escaped space!
```

It's also possible to construct pieces of regular expression separately via the 'qr' string prefix and combine them using variable substitution. Something like

```
my $num_re = qr/(\X+)\(\X(\d+.\d+|\d+)\/\X(\d+.\d+|\d+)/;
my ($foo, $bar, $etc) = $input_line =~ /^\d+: ....  $num_re (\X+)\)$/;
```

I have not done this for long, so I am not sure you whether any flags are needed.

Comment: It is indeed /x. Read all about it here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see in the regex is the period in '\d+.\d+'.

You know that '.' in a regex matches ANY character, not only an actual period character.

If you want to specify only an actual period character, you'll have to use '\.' instead.

The other thing is that you may be able to replace '\d+.\d+|\d+' with '\d+.?\d+'

[EDIT]
One more thing, if you use the interpolated regex more than once and don't change it in between uses, (say, in a loop), you should use the /o option to have Perl compile the entire regex so it doesn't need to be compiled everytime.